# sorting characters in an second array while replacing them with '*' in the old array

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I need to make a program that fills an array with Upcase chars and then sort those chars in a second array. It has to change every char in the old array with '*'and then put it in the second array(sorting is from the lowest ASCII code to the highest).

I did the first part and up until this point there's only one problem. My work doesn't function when I fill an array with the first item having the smallest ascii code, ex: `'A','C','E','F','G'`. The output for that one is : `T2[1] = A` and the rest of the T2 array is filled with stars.

Whereas if I don't put the first char as the lowest it works perfectly 
like : `'E','A','K'....`

```
program XD;
uses wincrt;
type 
  tab = array[1..100] of char;
var 
  t1,t2:tab;
  i,n ,k,p,o,v: integer;
begin
  repeat
    begin
      writeln('Donnez la taille T ');
      Readln(n);
    end;
  until(n in [5..20]);
  for i := 1 to n do 
    begin
      repeat
        begin
          writeln('Donnez T1[',i,']');
          readln(T1[i]);
        end;            
      until(UPCASE(T1[i]) = T1[i]);  
    end;
  for i := 1 to n do Begin    
    o := ord(T1[1]);
    for k := 2 to n do begin
      if (T1[K] <> '*') AND (ord(T1[k]) < o) then
        begin
          o := ord (T1[k]);
          p := k;
        End;
    end;
    T1[p] := '*';
    T2[v] := chr(o);
    v := v+1;
  end;
  for i := 1 to n do Begin    
    writeln('T2[',i,']=', T2[i]);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at the sorting algorithm. In the loop, you always start with the first item in the `T1` array and compare it with the rest.

> Whereas if I don't put the first char as the lowest it works perfectly ...

Now, what will happen when the first character is the lowest? Right, it will be replaced with a `*`, and the rest of the sorting will fail, since you will compare with the `Ord('*')` value, which is lower than any character value in the alphabet.

---

To fix the algorithm, compare with the loop index character and swap the lowest character with the loop index value at the end. That will keep the `'*'` characters out of the loop and the need to compare against them.

```
for i := 1 to n do begin    
  o := Ord(T1[i]);  // Pick actual loop index value
  p := i;  // Store index
  for k := i+1 to n do begin  // Search for lowest character
    if (Ord(T1[k]) < o) then begin
      o := ord (T1[k]);
      p := k;
    end;
  end;      
  // Swap the p and i index value, to put the * into the i index position
  if (i <> p) then 
    T1[p] := T1[i];
  T1[i] := '*';
  T2[i] := Chr(o);
end;
```